# Load UIImageView with TableView to another ViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

i hope you can help me!

Now i have a table view from this source [an iOS table view of 2014 world cup countries by groups](https://github.com/airbob/iOS-tableview-of-2014-world-cup)

Here you can see the code from the sidebarviewcontroller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.2f alpha:1.0f];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.0f];
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.15f alpha:0.2f];

grpArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Group A",@"Group B",@"Group C",@"Group D",@"Group E",@"Group F",@"Group G",@"Group H", nil];

NSArray* aArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"BRAZIL",@"CROATIA",@"MEXICO",@"CAMEROON", nil];
NSArray* bArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"SPAIN",@"NETHERLAND",@"CHILE",@"AUSTRALIA", nil];
NSArray* cArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"COLOMBIA",@"GREECE",@"CÔTE D'IVOIRE",@"JAPAN", nil];
NSArray* dArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"URUGUAY",@"COSTA RICA",@"ENGLAND",@"ITALY", nil];
NSArray* eArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"SWITZERLAND",@"ECUADOR",@"FRANCE",@"HONDURAS", nil];
NSArray* fArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ARGENTINA",@"BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA",@"IRAN",@"NIGERIA", nil];
NSArray* gArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"GERMANY",@"PORTUGAL",@"GHANA",@"USA", nil];
NSArray* hArr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"BELGIUM",@"ALGERIA",@"RUSSIA",@"KOREA REPUBLIC", nil];

tableArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aArr,bArr,cArr,dArr,eArr,fArr,gArr,hArr, nil];

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

return [grpArr count];

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section


return  [grpArr objectAtIndex:section];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

return  [[tableArr objectAtIndex:section] count];

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

return 44;
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"normalCell"];

NSString *tempCountry = [[tableArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:1];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:tempCountry];
UILabel *countryLabel = (UILabel*)[[cell contentView] viewWithTag:2];
countryLabel.text = tempCountry;


return cell;

- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
```

{

```
// Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showPhoto"]) {
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PhotoViewController *photoController = (PhotoViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_photo.png", [tableArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    photoController.photoFilename = photoFilename;
}

if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };

}
```

}

In my PhotoViewController i load the image in the viewDidLoad Method with the following line of code

```
 self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.photoFilename];
```

The problem is i cant load the image in the photoviewcontroller, the image is not showing. I want to show a ball with the brazil flag. my image named BRAZIL_photo.png. I think i have no connection to the nsarray objects!?
Where is the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [[tableArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] to get the name of a country out of your array, since the array is an array of arrays.

```
NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_photo.png", tableArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me! It is possible that i can load a row with the image on start up?

Comment: @blackyE, a row in what controller?

Comment: the brazil_photo.png in the photoviewcontroller?!

Comment: @blackyE, that controller isn't visible at start up, is it? You're segueing to that controller, so I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: the controller is visible at start up! I´m using a slidebar, the sidebarviewcontroller is not visible at start up until i swipe from the left but i want to load a row on start up because now i have to open the slide bar to view an image in the photoviewcontroller.

Comment: @blackyE, I haven't used a SWRevealViewController, so I'm not clear on what the controller structure of your app is. Are you saying that the PhotoViewController is the one visible at launch, but you need to swipe the sidebar open, and select a row for anything to appear there?

Comment: Yes, i need to select a row that a images appears in the photoviewcontroller! I want that a row is selected at start up and you dont need to open the sidebar.

Comment: @blackyE, you need to give PhotoViewController's photoFilename a default value at startup. You can test for whether photoFilename is nil in viewDidLoad, and if it is, give it a default value.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string in `prepareForSegue:` that is not the photo name. Therefore, the image view does not get populated.

When you get the image in the cell it presumably still works:

```
NSString *tempCountry = tableArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:tempCountry];
```

The image name is presumably `@"BRAZIL"` which is also valid for `@"BRAZIL.png"`.

When preparing for the segue, however, you are passing only the group array:

```
NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_photo.png", 
                           tableArr[indexPath.row]];
photoController.photoFilename = photoFilename;
```

The image name is now something along the lines of `@"<CFArray 0x45003F>.png"`. So you should pass the proper string instead:

```
    NSString *photoFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_photo.png", 
                           tableArr[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]];
```

Now the image name should be `@"BRAZIL_photo.png"`. Check your file names (including capitalisation) and you should find the error.

Your problem arises from your absurd data setup. One correct way to do this is to have a plist that holds the strings. You would achieve much more readable code if you created `NSObject` subclasses like `Group` and `Team` etc. with the proper attributes. If you intend to keep scores and game times etc., you should actually consider using Core Data from the beginning.